# WPF XAML Combo Box IsEnabled based on previous selection

Tags: wpf, xaml

In WPF XAML I'm wanting to make a combo box enabled only when the previous combo box has something selected in it. The 'top level' combo prompts the user to make a selection - so when they select something in the list then the next combo should become enabled.

Can I use a DataTemplate / Trigger to do this or can it be done with Element Binding?

Thanks folks.

Comment: It really depends on what you want to do and how you are doing it. For instance, if you are using a viewmodel you can simply define a boolean property that is switched to true when the selction of the previous combobox is changed. if you want a more precise answer you should give us some code snippets where you show what you have tried so far

Comment: Hi, I was hoping to do it all in XAML if possible. Something along the lines of IsEnabled="{Binding SelectedValue, ElementName=cboMachineType}"

Comment: you can make use of a [Converter](http://www.wpftutorial.net/valueconverters.html)

Comment: @Martin, please show code which you have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**you can try this**:

```
<ComboBox Name="comboBox1">
    <ComboBoxItem>Some Content</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Some More Content</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>

<ComboBox Name="comboBox2">
    <ComboBoxItem>Content Here</ComboBoxItem>        
        <ComboBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedItem , ElementName=comboBox1}" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
      </ComboBox.Style>
 </ComboBox>
```